# Key Remapping on Logitech K750

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permanently swapping option and command keys on a non-Apple keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/permanently-swapping-option-and-command-keys-on-a-non-apple-keyboard)

I have a Logitec K750 and it has the left Alt key closer to the space bar than the Windows Key (to be used as Command Key).  How can I remap the keys on JUST my Logitech keyboard and NOT on my built-in MacBook keyboard so that the Left Alt key functions like the Command Key, and the Left Command Key functions like the Left Alt key?  Is there a way to do this without having any apps running in the background, like some kind of key-map file I can edit rather than using a tool to do it? I'm a real resource-conscious user and don't want anything running in the background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this answered question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/permanently-swapping-option-and-command-keys-on-a-non-apple-keyboard).

The solution seems to remap all keyboards with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) and then remap just the internal keyboard with standard keyboard preferences pane. (not tested by myself)