# Can I use a non-Apple, Bluetooth keyboard with a MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, keyboard, wifi, bluetooth, mouse

I'm currently operating on a late 2013 MacBook Pro and am eager to buying a wireless keyboard for my setup. I was looking at the Logitech MK345, which is a bluetooth mouse-keyboard combo, and thought it was quite what I needed. Although, it didn't really say anywhere that it worked with Mac. I tried looking for answers to see if non-mac keyboards function properly with OS X and only saw answers for wired ones.

I'm pretty confused... Should I take the risk of buying the keyboard? Any suggestions to what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: This keyboard uses a USB dongle which *generally* work with MacOS. You are likely safe but buy it from a place that allows easy returns just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes in general. Bluetooth has an HID profile that lets mice and keyboard work with any other Bluetooth receiver that supports that profile. macOS and Mac hardware support the standard profile, so at worst, you are likely to need to remap windows specific keys and deal with no Apple specific keys.

- [Can I use a non-Apple keyboard with OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/can-i-use-a-non-apple-keyboard-with-os-x)

Unless the keyboard you buy requires some custom driver or isn't standard Bluetooth, you should have low chances of needing to return it or have it not work at all. In specific, you are looking at a USB keyboard not a Bluetooth one, so that's also going to work with the limitations that special keys and drivers and software won't work on macOS. The majority of the keys will work.

Comment: The MK345 uses the same unlicensed band 2.4 GHz as wifi and Bluetooth so it may cause interference if you need those to work too, but I've not had issues with that specific model in offices with lots of Bluetooth devices.